# Term for subgenre of heist film where main character is a 'genius'?

Tags: genre

Is there a term for a genre with "person v. society" narratives where a gifted main character attempts to exploit a system for great personal gain. The term I'm looking for describes movies that aren't necessarily heist films. While a bank or casino could be *one* target the gifted  protagonist could exploit, the protagonist's actions don't have to be illegal. The protagonist's actions only have to be extraordinary.

Here are some example films and TV shows I had in mind.

- *Catch Me If You Can* (2002)
- *21* (2008)
- *Moneyball* (2011)
- *Limitless* (2011)
- *Mr. Robot* (2015-2019)

Also, in this subgenre of movie, montages and voice-over narration are extremely common, and many (but not all) of these films are based on true events. What would you call these sorts of movies/shows?

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to find a satisfying term encompassing such a broad variety of films. Even just the examples you listed are a really eclectic collection.

Comment: you're probably looking for https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InsufferableGenius or something similar...most of your listed protagonists fall into some description of such a trope.

Comment: Maybe this post doesn't need additional details or more focus, but the answer is just "no, there is no name for that genre".

Comment: I don't have a specific answer but they all seem to be a form of 'aspirational' tv/film. Lex Luthor is a genius but his character arc frequently leads to 'pathetic' (like Jesse Eisenberg's portrayal) - spending all his time harassing a Kansas farmboy. The characters in these examples make you feel as if their world is worth exploring - that magic/math/trading/hacking is beautiful, their lives are a perfected version of your own, and their main character arc is to prove their greatness.